# TreeView with DropdownList

Tags: asp.net, treeview, web-controls

System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView shows hierarchical data in an expandable tree view with the possibility to have a checkbox next to each node.

I want something similar, but I need to render a DropDownList at each node, so I can have more than two choices (checked or unchecked).

Is there a way to do this with a TreeView?

Or is there another free control that does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about other free controls, but with a TreeView you can't do it w/o creating your own version or taking over rendering. The TreeView does not use Controls collection and does not provide a way to inject anything or change its render output.